# How should I interpret these integrals from Griffiths 'Intro to Electrodynamics'?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

The book defines the electric field at a point $P$ a distance $r$ due to a point charge $q$ as :

$$ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{q}{r^2}$$

it then tells us that the electric field at a point $P$ due to $n$ point charges $q_i$ is  :

$$ E = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{q}{r_i^2}  $$

where $r_i$ is the distance between $q_i$ and $P$. As in the electric field follows the superposition principle.

It then tells us that when we have instead of discrete point charges, have a continuous charge (either a line charge, a surface charge, or volume charge) then the electric fields given for the respective situations are given as :

1. $$ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{}^{}  \frac{\lambda(r')}{r^2}dl' $$
2. $$ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{}^{}  \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}da' $$
3. $$ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{}^{}  \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}d \tau' $$

Where for a line charge : $dq= \lambda dl' $,

for a surface charge : $dq = \sigma da'$

for a volume charge : $dq = \rho d\tau'$

---

Here's where my question comes in, I am having a great trouble understanding how to 'interpret' these integrals.

Firstly, I tried viewing these integrals mathematically. For example for the surface charge integral (eq 2.) I tried to express it as the Electric field at a point $P$ due to a charged rectangle in cartesian coordinates of length $a$ and width $b$ :

$$ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{area}^{}  \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}da' = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{area}^{}  \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}dx'dy' = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0}(\int_{0}^{a} (\int_{0}^{b}  \frac{\sigma(r')}{(\sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 + (y_1 - y)^2)}^2}dx')dy') $$

Where $r$ is the distance of each point in the rectangle to the point $P = (x_1,y_1)$ from the arbitrary points to integrate over $(x,y)$,  (assuming the charged rectangle and $P$ are on the same plane here. [I made a rough paint to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgHGg.jpg)

- I tried to interpret the last expression on the RHS as the volume above a rectangle of length $a$ and width $b$, with a height of function $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}$. Where the 'height' of each point above this rectangle, is the magnitude of the contribution for a point charge located at that point. Kind of like the height above each point is $dE$ at $P$, and adding them all together gives us $E$ at $P$. [I made another rough paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp5Yy.jpg). But we're talking about 'surface charges' not point charges. So this interpretation *shouldn't* hold for a line charge, because it uses a different variable for some reason ($\lambda$ instead of $\sigma$). But I don't see why you can't similarly just interpret equation 1. as the area above a line with height $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \int_{}^{}  \frac{\lambda(r')}{r^2}dl'$, similar to how one interprets definite integrals in Integral Calculus. Which leads to my second question
- Why are we using different terms for the integration variable? At first I thought it was so you get the correct units but I'm not so sure how to justify that intuition. How does the integral 'know' I'm talking about areas when I say $da'$ and lines or volumes when I say $dl'$ and $d\tau '$?
- The easiest way I've found to think of all this is to think of the function under the integral 'as a whole'. As in to think of equation 2. As taking an infinitesmal area of the charged rectangle (surface element $da'$) and multiplying it by the charge density ($\sigma(r')$), which would give you the total charge on the surface element ($dq$). Then picking a point on this infinitesmal surface area and measuring the distance from this point to $P$ (this distance would be $r$). Then multiplying this entire expression by $\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon _0}$. Which gives the expression

$$ dE = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2}da' = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{dq}{r^2}$$

as the electric field due to a singular surface element a distance $r$ away from a point $P$. And then when you take the integral of this above expression, since integrals represent infinite sums, the above integrated would represent adding up the contribution of all these surface elements, to give the total electric field of the entire surface. And this makes a lot of sense to me, however it is not *actually* how integration works to my knowledge.
What I've described is multiplying the area of a bunch of squares ($da$) by a factor dependent on this squares position and charge density ($\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon _0} \frac{\sigma(r')}{r^2})$ . Which gives an associated $dE$ with each square, and adding them (integrating) to get an $E$ associated with the whole rectangle. To my knowledge integrating the above expression over a rectangle for example, would be to integrate the contribution of a line on this rectangle, with its height determined as $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _0} \frac{dq}{r^2}$ , then sweeping it along the rectangle. My calculus professor made a demo of what I mean [here](https://www.math3d.org/7ro2zcwPz).

---

Sorry if this question is extremely long or difficult to follow. Part of my question is me not really understanding what I'm missing about how to interpret these integrals. I suspect I also have some fundamental flaw in my understanding of integrals that I'm missing. Any answers appreciated.

Comment: Why is the $r$ in the denominator not primed like the integration variable?

Comment: technically they're vectors in griffiths definitions. r′ is the vector from the origin to the source charge. P represents the vector from the origin to the point we want to test the electric field at. r is defined as the vector from the source charge r′, to P. As in r = P - r′ . rough drawing : https://imgur.com/a/pSXYgpN

Comment: OK, makes sense. I still don't understand your problem though. From point 3, you seem to have a firm grasp of what is happening. Yet, you seem to have a mental block due to some misconception about integrals I can't figure out.

Comment: It seems you're confused that one the one hand an integral is the surface under the curve determined by a function and on the other in this specific case it is the integral of the field density over a line/surface/volume. Well both are true and there is no contradiction.

Comment: just observe that $dq$ is the density of charges in the line/surface/volume so $\int \frac{dq}{r^2}$ is the sum of all the contributions

Comment: “And then when you take the integral of this above expression, since integrals represent infinite sums, the above integrated would represent adding up the contribution of all these surface elements, to give the total electric field of the entire surface. And this makes a lot of sense to me,” Correct! “however it is not actually how integration works to my knowledge.” Yes it is. This must be your point of confusion. The way integration works is that you chop up the region you’re integrating over into tiny pieces, compute the contribution of each tiny piece, and add up all the contributions.

Comment: “To my knowledge integrating the above expression over a rectangle for example, would be to integrate the contribution of a line on this rectangle, with its height determined as … then sweeping it along the rectangle” I suspect the confusion is due to thinking of integration like this. When integrating a function $f$ over a region $R$ in $\mathbb R^2$, we do the following: 1) chop up $R$ into tiny pieces; 2) the contribution of ith piece is $f(x_i) \Delta A_i$, where $x_i$ is a point in the ith piece and $\Delta A_i$ is area of $i$th piece; 3) $\int_R f \, dA \approx \sum_i f(x_i) \Delta A_i$.